# SQL query to get the status of all the job in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I need a SQL query which should give me the latest status of all the jobs in SQL server.

Below Query i have tried to get the status but it will not give the status of all the jobs in SQL server.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT name AS [Job Name],
    CASE WHEN enabled=1 THEN 'Enabled'  
        ELSE 'Disabled'  
    END [Job Status],
    CASE    WHEN SJH.run_status=0 THEN 'Failed'
            WHEN SJH.run_status=1 THEN 'Succeeded'
            WHEN SJH.run_status=2 THEN 'Retry'
            WHEN SJH.run_status=3 THEN 'Cancelled'
    ELSE 'Unknown'  
    END [Job Outcome],
    sjh.run_date,
    sjh.run_time
FROM    SYSJobs sj
LEFT    JOIN    SYSJobHistory sjh
ON      sj.job_id = sjh.job_id
WHERE   (
    sjh.run_date IN (
                    SELECT  MAX(sjh1.run_date)
                    FROM    SYSJobHistory sjh1
                    WHERE   sjh.job_id = sjh1.job_id
                    )
    OR sjh.run_date IS NULL
    )
AND     (
    sjh.run_time IN (
                    SELECT  MAX(sjh1.run_time)
                    FROM    SYSJobHistory sjh1
                    WHERE   sjh.job_id = sjh1.job_id
                    )
    OR  sjh.run_time IS NULL
    )
 ORDER  BY [Job Name]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using `Row_Number()`

```
;With Cte
as
(
    SELECT  name AS [Job Name],
        CASE WHEN enabled=1 THEN 'Enabled'  
            ELSE 'Disabled'  
        END [Job Status],
      CASE    WHEN SJH.run_status=0 THEN 'Failed'
        WHEN SJH.run_status=1 THEN 'Succeeded'
        WHEN SJH.run_status=2 THEN 'Retry'
        WHEN SJH.run_status=3 THEN 'Cancelled'
        ELSE 'Unknown'  
        END [Job Outcome],
        sjh.run_date,
        sjh.run_time,Row_Number() Over(Partition by name Order By sjh.run_date desc,sjh.run_time desc) as rn
    FROM    SYSJobs sj
    LEFT    JOIN    SYSJobHistory sjh
    ON      sj.job_id = sjh.job_id
)

select * from cte where rn=1
```

If You din't Understand the scenario, then just look at the [**Row_Number()**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms186734.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your Support. The Query is working as Expected.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
select distinct j.Name as "Job Name", 
case jh.run_status  
when 0 then 'Failed'  
when 1 then 'Successful'  
when 2 then 'Retry' 
when 3 then 'Cancelled'  
when 4 then 'In Progress'  
end as Job_Execution_Status 
from sysJobHistory jh, sysJobs j 
where j.job_id = jh.job_id
```

Comment: Thank you for your Support. The Query is working but it is giving the status of each step in the Job. I need the status of job instead of Steps in the Job

Comment: 4 is no longer supported in sql2008 upwards